# How can I use ServiceStack client with Xamarin.Android Indie License

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, servicestack, xamarin

When I compile my Xamarin.Android application which is linked with ServiceStack compiled dll, compilation failed with message:

> Error XA9003: Assembly `System.ServiceModel, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` requiresﾂBusinessﾂ(or higher) License. (XA9003)

I compile it with [this ServiceStack compiled dll](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/release/latest/MonoDroid)

How can I use ServiceStack client with Xamarin.Android Indie License?

- Is there any dll not linked with WCF?
- Need to be compile from source?
- Other way?

Answer (score 1):

Free license will not allowed few functions. You can check out documentation for details [here.](https://store.xamarin.com/)

Check the unlimited app size part it will give answer of your issue. It is stopping P/Invoke in third party.

I suggest you go with traditional android way to grab json (I hope you are trying that only.). And don't add service stack directly in project.

If there is anything let me know.

Comment: The OP asked about the Indie License, which allows P/Invoke, not the free one. Do you have any experience and suggestions for doing what is being asked with the Indie License Xamarin?

Comment: It seemed like you were addressing the Free License of Xamarian.Android. I guess not?

Comment: @JeremyCook Yup. I were. But I don't have any updated news. Long time pass since I have checked Xamarin. :(